# MySQL query 2 tables, 1 insert

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm trying to pull data from 2 tables and then insert result into a third table. My code follows but only does 1 correct entry, and the rest are blank. There are 348 entries total. What am I missing here?

```
$dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:$mysqldatabase:$mysqlhostname",
    "$mysqlusername",
    "$mysqlpassword"
);

if(!$dbh) { die("Error: could not get DBI handle\n"); }
$sqlConnect = 1;

$SQL =<<SQL;
SELECT * FROM oscmax2.info2
SQL

$sth = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
if(!$sth) { die("Error: " . $dbh->errstr . "\n"); }
if(!$sth->execute) { die("Error4: " . $sth->errstr . "\n"); }

while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    $products_id = $FORM{'product_id'};
    $affiliate_id = $FORM{'affiliate_id'};
    $demo = $FORM{'demo'};
}

if($sth->rows != 0) {
    $total_rows = $sth->rows;

    for ($counter = 0; $counter < $total_rows; $counter++) {

        $SQL =<<SQL;
SELECT products_attributes_id FROM oscmax2.products_attributes
WHERE  products_id = '$products_id'
SQL

        $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
        if(!$sth) { die("Error: " . $dbh->errstr . "\n"); }
        if(!$sth->execute) { die("Error: " . $sth->errstr . "\n");}

        while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
            $products_attributes_id = $FORM2{'products_attributes_id'};
        }

        $SQL =<<SQL;
INSERT INTO oscmax2.products_attributes_download(
    products_attributes_id,      products_attributes_filename,
    products_attributes_maxdays, products_attributes_maxcount
)
VALUES
('$products_attributes_id', '$affiliate_id/$demo', '7', '1')
SQL

        $dbh->do($SQL) || die("Error5: " . $dbh->errstr . "\n");
    }
}

$sth->finish();

if($sqlConnect) { $dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: I don't know perl, but it sure looks like you're just reassigning the value of the variables `$products_id`, `$affiliate_id`, and `$demo` in that first `while()` loop.

Comment: THere is a bunch of stuff mixed up in your code. Some of it is because of non-lexical variables. You should always `use strict` and `use warnings`. Also your code is not complete and will not compile. There is a `}` missing at the end.

Comment: What is the role of `%FORM`? is this a CGI script and you are getting input from a website?

Answer (score 2):

The blocks

```
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    $products_id = $FORM{'product_id'};
    $affiliate_id = $FORM{'affiliate_id'};
    $demo = $FORM{'demo'};
}
```

and

```
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    $products_attributes_id = $FORM2{'products_attributes_id'};
}
```

are wrong. You use `@row` to accept the data from each row of the result, but never use it. The database fetch won't affect `%FORM` and `%FORM2` so you are just collecting the same data from them several times over

#### Update

At a guess you want something like this. Please *study* it and use the techniques rather than copying and testing it as it is, as I have no way of knowing what the structure of your database is and I have made several guesses

You should note the following points

- There is no need to test the status of each DBI operation and `die` if it failed. By default the `PrintError` option is enabled and DBI will raise a warning if there are any errors. If you want your program to `die` instead, which is wise, then you can enable `RaiseError` and disable `PrintError` and DBI will do it all for you
- There is no need to fetch all of the data from a table into memory (which I think is what you are trying to do with your `while` loops. You should fetch *each row* into an array and process the data row by row unless you have a reason to do otherwise
- You should *always* `prepare` your statement and *use placeholders*. Then you can pass the actual parameters to the `execute` call and DBI will correctly quote them for you. Furthermore you can move all the `prepare` calls top the top of the program, making your logic much clearer to read
- There is almost never a reason to call `finish` or `disconnect`. Perl will do the right thing for you when your database or statement handles go out of scope or your program ends
- I have named the statement handles `$select1` and `$select2`. These are very poor names, but I don't know the structure of your database so I couldn't write anything better. That shouyldn't stop you from improving them
- I have had to guess at the columns returned by the first SELECT statement. If the three variables don't correspond to the first three elements of `@row` then you need to correct that
- You should avoid using capital letters in Perl lexical identifiers. They are reserved for globals like package names, and nasty clashes of purpose can be caused if you don't abide by this rule

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($mysqldatabase, $mysqlhostname, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) = qw/ dbase host user pass /;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:$mysqldatabase:$mysqlhostname",
    "$mysqlusername",
    "$mysqlpassword",
    {RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0}
) or die "Unable to connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

my $select1 = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM oscmax2.info2');

my $select2 = $dbh->prepare(<<__END_SQL__);
SELECT products_attributes_id FROM oscmax2.products_attributes\
WHERE  products_id = ?
__END_SQL__

my $insert = $dbh->prepare(<<__END_SQL__);
INSERT INTO oscmax2.products_attributes_download (
    products_attributes_id,
    products_attributes_filename,
    products_attributes_maxdays,
    products_attributes_maxcount
)
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )
__END_SQL__

$select1->execute;

while ( my @row = $select1->fetchrow_array ) {

    my ($products_id, $affiliate_id, $demo) = @row;

    $select2->execute($products_id);

    while ( my @row = $select2->fetchrow_array ) {

        my ($products_attributes_id) = @row;

        $insert->execute($products_attributes_id, "$affiliate_id/$demo", 7, 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow you're on a roll. I started doing the same and building the two selects into one with a join, but I gave up because I didn't want to guess what the form does.

Comment: @simbabque: That's exactly why I didn't write a JOIN. There's not much to go on in the question, but I think this is basically right. We'll have to wait and see

Comment: I agree. Looks pretty good now. Just the two `@row`s are not optimal I think, and I'd probably go with `fetchrow_hashref` or `fetchrow_arrayref` if speed is an issue. But lets keep it simple I guess.